# 'interface' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

***EDIT:  After @mattytommo's help in isolating the root-cause of the error, I discovered that the IStatementRepository.cs file was not included in the project.  Including it in the project resolved this case.***

I am trying to implement a repository on my controller ( with some Dependency Injection thrown in), but I'm bumping into a wall.  I have an IStatementRepository defined, But, when I try to create a constructor with an IStatementRepository parameter for DI purposes, I get the following errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'IStatementRepository' does not 
exist in the namespace 'StatementsApplication.Models' (are 
you missing an assembly reference?) 

The type or namespace name 'IStatementRepository' could 
not be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)    

'StatementsApplication.Controllers.StatementController' 
does not contain a definition for 'IStatementRepository' 
and no extension method 'IStatementRepository' accepting a 
first argument of type 
'StatementsApplication.Controllers.StatementController' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

Here's the block of code where the errors are generated:

```
using StatementsApplication.Models;

namespace StatementsApplication.Controllers
{
    public class StatementController : Controller
    {
        public StatementsApplication.Models.IStatementRepository _repo;

        private DALEntities db = new DALEntities();

        public StatementController(IStatementRepository repository)
        {
            this.IStatementRepository = repository;
        }

        // additional controller actions here
    }
}
```

And here is the entire contents of IStatementRepository.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using StatementsApplication.DAL;

namespace StatementsApplication.Models
{
    public interface IStatementRepository    {
        IEnumerable<Statement> findAll();
        IEnumerable<Statement> findByMerchantID(int id);
        Statement findByID(int id);
        Statement createStatement(Statement stmt);
        int saveChanges();
        void deleteStatement(int id);

    }
}
```

I can't see why I can't utilize an interface here.  All the examples I'm following seem to be using this general patter, so I expect I'm just missing something simple.

I will be very grateful for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor is a little off, you're trying to do `this.IStatementRepository`, yet the variable is `this._repo`. Those errors are because Visual Studio is telling you there isn't a variable called `IStatementRepository` inside `this` (your controller) :).

Try this:

```
using StatementsApplication.Models;

namespace StatementsApplication.Controllers
{
    public class StatementController : Controller
    {
        public StatementsApplication.Models.IStatementRepository _repo;

        private DALEntities db = new DALEntities();

        public StatementController(IStatementRepository repository)
        {
            this._repo = repository;
        }

        // additional controller actions here
    }
}
```

Comment: that fixes the bottom-most of the three errors, but I'm still getting errors tracking down IStatementRepository on the first and third lines of the controller code.

Comment: @reidLinden Can you post the code for `IStatementRepository` **including** the namespace?

Comment: @reidLinden Hmm strange, are they in the same project? If not, does the project that contains the Controller have a reference to the project that contains the interface?

Comment: yep, same project...I have only the main project, and the beginnings of a unit test project (which is how I ended up doing the repository thing, ending up here)

Comment: @reidLinden Very strange, can you see it in the intellisense when you type `StatementsApplication.Models.` in the controller? Can you see any other class inside that namespace?

Comment: @reidLinden So there are two `.cs` files, right? How are you trying to compile? With VS? Are there any more files in your project? **Are these the only errors you get?** Is the file IStatementRepository.cs actually compiled (will you get an error if you omit a semicolon `;` in that file)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - yes, multiple files, no, not the only ones.  Yes, the only errors I get when compiling.  Not sure how to compile a single file by itself, especially when that file has dependencies on other files anyhow...  This is in vs2010 ... anyhow, removing all "statement" related stuff from the interface so its just dealing with primitive types, I get the same errors.  Not sure if that tells us anything or not, but, FYI

Comment: @redLinden Just for testing purposes, try moving the `interface` inside the controller file and update the usage. Does it still complain/

Comment: @mattytommo - yes, that clears the complaints, but thats not really what I want to be doing, is it ?

Comment: @reidLinden Nah but it highlights the fact that the `interface` isn't the problem, it's the namespace/controller's access to that namespace that's the problem, hmmm...

Comment: Hah!  Found it.  I was getting ready to take a screenshot for @mattytommo and, noticed that of all the *.cs files in my project, only the IStatementRepository.cs file didn't have the green 'c#' icon, only a plain white one.  A little investigation showed me that the file, for reasons beyond me (since I added the classes from within VS, via "add | class..."), the file was not included in the project!  As soon as I fixed that, it immediately compiled.  I'm awarding the correct answer to this question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @reidLinden Ahhh yeah, I hate it when that happens! No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

If your interface is in a different assembly, is it marked as `public`?

Is the build action of your interface file set to Compile?

Comment: Surely that couldn't be the case as his code wouldn't even compile? :)

Comment: I have a  "using StatementsApplication.Models;" in the controller code, if that's what your asking.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what else I'd need.

Comment: @reidLinden What code are you actually using to create the DI instance of your class?

Comment: @mattytommo - I haven't gotten that far yet...figured I needed to fix this compile error before I moved on to using Ninject to actually do the work.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki - Not in a different assembly, just a different namesspace.  But the interface IS public.... "public interface IStatementRepository    {"

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```